# Git: Cannot change author name/committer name with $ git config --global user.name

Tags: git, macos, github

When I push changes to github, a wrong author name appears. I tried to change the settings globally and for the specific repository with

`$ git config --global user.name "Right Name"`

and

`$ git config user.name "Right Name"`

but that didn't help. I deleted the credentials stored in Keychain Access with no success.

I changed the author name only for the next commit with:

`$ git commit --author="Right Name <right@name.org>"`

It resulted in: "Right Name authored and Wrong Name committed" on Github.

`$ git config --list`

shows "Right Name" but still on Github the author name is "Wrong Name". What am I doing wrong?

(Please note: I don't need to change the author of previous commits. I just would like to commit with the right author name in the future)

Comment: By "name you are using on Github" you mean my account name? The one in the URL: github.com/ACCOUNTNAME? If yes: That doesn't help because my account name isn't the wrong name showing up as "author" when I push. And which answer exactly do you recommend in the link you posted? The first and accepted one is what I already did (as I wrote).

Comment: I ask you to please open the question again because the answer given and the link given in the answer are not the solution to my problem.

Comment: I assume that you have no magic power. I asked to reopen the post because Stackoverflow recommended exactly that: "Leave a comment on the question itself calling for it to be reopened." https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions. To me it seems Stack Overflow works like that. So here I am, having no answer to my question because I did all that is said in the link BEFORE I opened my question. And the name I use on Github is not the name showing up as the author. So the problem has to be somewhere else and I have no idea what to do. But thanks.